# Azure Local Storage and Azure Virtual Machine HD

Tags: azure, local-storage

Is there a difference between storing files in the Local Storage than storing on the Azure Virtual Machine HD (like d:\ or e:)? From what I am understand, they are the same.

THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you wanted to compare local storage with Azure Virtual Machin's HDs because local storage is applicable to Web/Worker Role scenarios (PaaS) while virtual machine hard disk is applicable to persistent VM scenarios (IaaS). More apt comparison would be between local storage and Azure drives.

From what I understand, the local storage in Windows Azure is temporary. What that means is that if your role instance goes down and can't be recovered, anything stored in local storage is gone. Secondly local storage is specific to a role instance and you can't share this across role instances. Thirdly, maximum size of the local storage is limited by the size of your role instance. For example, if your application is deployed in a "Small" sized VM, the maximum amount of local storage you can have is 229.4 MB (ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh369931.aspx).

Comparing that to Azure Virtual Machine HD, they're persistent storage backed by Windows Azure Blob Storage. These are saved as Page Blobs in Blob Storage. Because of this fact, you can have up to 1 TB (max. size of a page blob) of storage available to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Local Storage in Azure can persist between role recycles and even redeployments. Local Storage is much faster to access.

Comment: @chrisb ... agreed that the local storage is persisted between role recycles. I am not sure about redeployments though. Can you share a link where it talks about redeployment scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Can't find anywhere it's documented, but we definitely do this in production. We store a big datafile 200GB in local storage so it would be impractical for us to re-download this from blob every time we re-deployed.

Answer (score 0):

The files should be stored in BLOB storage. I wouldn't save any files in the VM disk except like MongoDB. The VM file is on the blob storage. If it is permanent it should be on BLOB, temporary I would save it on local.